# VSCode will not stop on breakpoints when first node prcess forks a second

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, child-process

The first issue is that there is some conflict error when you do the following from your app.js file and hit F5 to debug:

var cp = require('child_process');
var node2 = cp.fork('./app_FORK.js');

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::15838
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)

I had the same issue with VS Community, so I did the following there and it worked:
var node2 = cp.fork('./app_FORK.js', [], { execArgv: ['--debug=5859'] });

However, in VS Code, it does not seem to work. I place breakpoints, or try to attach after launching node from the command line and it errors out.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to configure your launch.json file in the .vscode folder in order to attach the debugger to the child process.

`json
{ "name": "Attach to Node", "type": "node", "address": "localhost", "port": 5859, }`

Just spawn the child process on the correct port (can set above) and use the --debug or --debug-brk argument.