# Debug Node.JS on VS Code EADDRINUSE error

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a Node.JS application on VS Code but, when the terminal opens, I get this message:

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5858

My application uses a framework called StrawJS (https://github.com/simonswain/straw) and it starts some different processes at the same time. I think that this is the cause of the error because there are many different processes trying to use the same debugger.

I found a similar question ([VSCode will not stop on breakpoints when first node prcess forks a second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109857/vscode-will-not-stop-on-breakpoints-when-first-node-prcess-forks-a-second)) but configure the port on the attach.js file didn't work, the problem persists.

This is my actual launch.json file:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 5858,
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/run.js",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "preLaunchTask": null,
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy"
        ],
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        "externalConsole": true,
        "sourceMaps": false,
        "outDir": null
    }
]}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I've  got this error because node finds this port already being used by another process... have you tried a different port?

Comment: Yes, I've tried some different ports

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. If you started the node --debug from CMD, you have to only Attach to Process in your VS Code (if you try to launch it again from VS Code on the same port it will cause an error - this was my mistake).

Define the attach configuration object in launch.json with something like this:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach to Process",
    "port": 5858
}
```

choose Attach to Process in the dropdown in the upper left corner and press green play button - Start Debugging.

Comment: Will your above excellent answer which I just awarded reputation points still work if I combine your Attach to [Node] Process object with a (gdb) Launch Process object in a VSCode compound launch configuration  and choose the compound launch option in the dropdown in the upper left corner and press green play button - Start Debugging.so I can seamlessly step into a node.js process which calls a custom C++ addon first followed by stepping into the C++ addon's breakpoints and then return to the original node.js process for breakpoint debugging? Thank you.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I have no experience with addons. However, this is just a procedure how to attach VSCode to node; it should have no impact on combining debuggers.

Comment: The problem of EADDRINUSE: PORT 5858 only occurs for me on my  my DELL WINDOWS 10 laptop running  RedHat Linux virtual box with node v6.11.1 installed  when the DELL laptop is docked and connected to the company ethernet network. The EADDRINUSE problem doesn't occur when I am not hooked to a company network. A coworker told me he thought port 5858 might be already used by a proxy, maybe http-proxy, But when I ran netstat on both Windows 10 terminal and the RedHat Linux virtual box when EADDRINUSE  happened, there was no entry for port 5858.How do I fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible for the VSCode IDE to jump between 2 node processes from CMD such as node debug main.js and node debug app.js while debugging them with VSCode's IDE debuggers with breakpoints? If so, what should my launch.json look look like? Also, do I need to start a Firefox VSCode debug adapter in a CMD terminal? I would like to use node debug main.js rather than node --debug main.js. Thank you very much.